# Mat table with 2 footers in the same column

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to have a mat table with 2 footers for all columns, but so far I haven't known how. SO please if anyone could help.

Comment: check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcjanw?file=src/app/table-footer-row-example.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mat-table with multiple footers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101838/mat-table-with-multiple-footers)